# How to modify XWPFRun object to hyperlink without creating new run

Tags: java, apache-poi

I want to update XWPFRun text to a hyperlink without creating a new run. If I try to do so, I get this error java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Value too large for the parameter position in XWPFRun.setText(String value,int pos)

```
private void updateRunsForParagraph1(XWPFParagraph p, String text, String key, Map<String, String> hyperlinkMap, Map<String, List<Boolean>> singleWordMap,SBCFormatDocument sbcFormatDocumentObj) throws IOException {

        for (int i = 0; i < p.getRuns().size(); i++) {
            try {
                String tmpText = p.getRuns().get(i).toString();

                if (tmpText != null && tmpText.equalsIgnoreCase(text)) {
                    //p.removeRun(i);
                    String[] subText = text.split(" ");
                    int subTextIndex = 0;
                    while (subTextIndex < subText.length) {
                        String word = subText[subTextIndex];

                        if (hyperlinkMap.keySet().contains(word) && tmpText.equalsIgnoreCase(text)) {
                            //p.createHyperlinkRun(word).setText(word, 0);
                            p.insertNewHyperlinkRun(subTextIndex + i, word).setText(word, i);
                            //p.insertNewRun(subTextIndex + i + 1).setText(" ", 0);

                        }

                        underLineAndHyperLinkWordsforParagraph(p, word, subTextIndex + i,hyperlinkMap,singleWordMap,sbcFormatDocumentObj);

                        subTextIndex++;
                    }
                    break;
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What Apache POI version used?

Comment: <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.2</version>
        </dependency>

Comment: Can you upgrade to current version 5.2.3? That has [XWPFParagraph.insertNewHyperlinkRun](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFParagraph.html#insertNewHyperlinkRun-int-java.lang.String-) to insert a `XWPFHyperlinkRun` on special position of paragraph instead only appending it at the end of paragraph. Then insert `XWPFHyperlinkRun` before found `XWPFRun`, copy text and main formats from found `XWPFRun` to the new `XWPFHyperlinkRun` and then remove found `XWPFRun`.

Comment: I tried after the upgrade with latest 5.2.3 . Still I am getting the error   java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Value too large for the parameter position in XWPFRun.setText(String value,int pos). Please refer the latest code snipet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not able to follow your usage of  [XWPFParagraph.insertNewHyperlinkRun](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFParagraph.html#insertNewHyperlinkRun-int-java.lang.String-), especially what that `subTextIndex` shall be for. And why using `i`, which is the position of the text run in the paragraph, as text position in `XWPFHyperlinkRun.setText`?

The main problem while replacing text runs in a Word document is to have correct text runs at all. Microsoft Word splits text in text runs for an arbitrary amount of reasons. So such approaches only can work, when the text run to replace is clearly formatted to really be a text run of it's own. Only If that is given, then one can find the text run to replace.

But creating a hyperlink cannot be done only by replacing something of a found `XWPFRun`. The hyperlink surrounds the text run. So the former `XWPFRun` must be surrounded by the new `XWPFHyperlinkRun` . To do so, one can insert a `XWPFHyperlinkRun` in paragraph before found `XWPFRun`, copy text and main formats from found `XWPFRun` to the new `XWPFHyperlinkRun` and then remove found `XWPFRun`.

Following complete example does that. It surrounds found text runs with a hyperlink and replaces text. It bases on a Word document where the placeholder "helloURL" clearly is formatted to be a text run of it's own.

`source.docx`:

[image]

Code:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class WordXWPFRunToXWPFHyperlinkRun {
    
 static List<XWPFParagraph> paragraphs = null;  
     
 static void findParagraphsContainigText(IBody body, String text) {
  for (IBodyElement bodyElement : body.getBodyElements()) {
   if (bodyElement instanceof XWPFParagraph) {
    XWPFParagraph paragraph = (XWPFParagraph)bodyElement;
    if (paragraph.getText().contains(text)) {
     paragraphs.add(paragraph);  
    }
   } else if (bodyElement instanceof XWPFTable) {
    XWPFTable table = (XWPFTable)bodyElement;
    for (XWPFTableRow tableRow : table.getRows()) {
     for (ICell tableICell : tableRow.getTableICells()) {
      if (tableICell instanceof XWPFTableCell) {
       XWPFTableCell tableCell = (XWPFTableCell)tableICell;
       findParagraphsContainigText(tableCell, text);
      }
     }
    }
   }
  }
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  try (   
        XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument(new FileInputStream("./source.docx"));
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("./result.docx") ) {
   String key = "helloURL"; 
   String replacement = "stackoverflow"; 
   String uri = "https://stackoverflow.com";  
   paragraphs = new ArrayList<XWPFParagraph>();    
   findParagraphsContainigText(document, key);
   for (XWPFParagraph paragraph : paragraphs) {
    List<XWPFRun> runs = paragraph.getRuns();
    for (int i = 0; i < runs.size(); i++ ) {
     XWPFRun run = runs.get(i);
     String text = run.getText(0);
     if (text.contains(key)) {
      text = text.replace(key, replacement);
      //insert hyperlink run before run
      XWPFHyperlinkRun hyperlinkRun = paragraph.insertNewHyperlinkRun(i, uri);
      //set CTR of hyperlink run the same as run
      hyperlinkRun.getCTHyperlink().setRArray(0, run.getCTR());
      //set textrun's text
      hyperlinkRun.setText(text, 0);
      //set hyperlinkk formats
      hyperlinkRun.setColor("0000FF");
      hyperlinkRun.setUnderline(UnderlinePatterns.SINGLE);
      //remove old run
      paragraph.removeRun(i+1);
     }
    }        
   } 
   document.write(out);
  }
 }
}
```

`result.docx`:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. Your logical explanation aligns perfectly with my implementations.